# Proving that a graph that is connected but not complete has vertices u,v and w such that uv and vw are edges but not uw

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

The task is prove that a graph G(V, E) that is connected but not complete there are vertices u, v and w such that uv,vw are in E but vw is not in E.

First off I'm not sure this is true. u and w could be connected to a vertices that is not v but that one is connected to v so it is a connected graph.

If I were to prove it I would start by saying "since G is not complete there exists vertices v and w that do not have an edge connecting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: That’s a good start. Now use the fact that $G$ is connected to conclude that there is a shortest path $v=v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n=w$ from $v$ to $w$.

- Why must it be true that $n\ge 2$?
- If this is really the shortest path from $v$ to $w$, the vertices $v,v_1$, and $v_2$ have the property that you want; why?

Comment: I'm confused by the notation v and w are two distinct vertices and `v=v0,v1,…,vn=w` you seem to be saying is an edge?

Comment: @Celeritas: No, it’s a path: for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$ there is an edge from $v_k$ to $v_{k+1}$. I simply listed the vertices along the path in the order in which they’re encountered in traversing the path from $v$ to $w$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: assume that this graph possesses the property that $$\forall u,v,w\in V:\ uv\in E, vw\in E \Rightarrow uw\in E.$$

What is that graph's diameter $d$ -- that is, the maximum graph distance between two different vertices? If $d=1$ then this is a complete graph. If $d>1$ then for some vertices $u$, $v$ the shortest path connecting them has length $d>1$. This path is $u_0u_1\ldots u_{d-1}u_d$ ($u = u_0$, $v = u_d$) -- then you can start moving along that path proving by induction that $u_i$ is directly connected with $u_0$ for each $i$...